# Delete the # char from the url

Tags: javascript, html, css

hey I'm having a little issue. Right now my navigator bar just take me to sections on my page. I did it using id which will connect the a tag to a specific section.
I get to see the # char with the section name on the url for example:

> http://orelhindi.s3-website.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/#skills

is there a way to make it dissapear?

```html
  <div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#cv">cv</a></li>
          <li><a href="#skills">skills</a></li>
          <li><a href="#portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      ....
       <section id="skills" data-aos="fade-right">
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fab fa-java"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-js-square"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-node"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-angular"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-html5"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-git"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-aws"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```

thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd recommend to keep. It allows people to directly link to sections of your page.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand - you want to be able to navigate to a section without including the `#whatever` part of the URL?

Comment: use a JS plugin for one page scroll ... there is a lot of them

Comment: @MikeTheLiar Sounds sub-optimal.

Comment: @Amy it's not even DOM optimal _badum tis_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically yes: [How to modify the URL without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-to-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page). Or you need to implement the scroll in JavaScript, making your life slightly more difficult.

And the # is useful, if someone shares the link anyone clicking on it will scroll to the correct place on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to Bob's answer. You can use JS to listen for the clicks and scroll the element into view.

1. Change all `href` to `data-section-id`
2. Using JS: query those `a[data-section-id]` elements
3. Add click event listener
4. Find the element with same id as `data-section-id`, and scroll it into view

Worth noting the support for [scrollIntoView](https://caniuse.com/#search=scrollIntoView).

```js
// When DOM is ready
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    
 // Get all `a` elements with `data-section-id`
 document.querySelectorAll("a[data-section-id]").forEach(aElement => {
     
  // Add click event listener
  aElement.addEventListener("click", event => {
      
   // Store the element with `id` matching `data-section-id`
   const scrollToElement = document.getElementById(event.target.dataset.sectionId);

   // If element is not null, scroll to it
   if (scrollToElement !== null) {
    scrollToElement.scrollIntoView();
   }
  });
 });
});
```

```html
<div class="menu">
        <ul>
          <li><a data-section-id="about">About</a></li>
          <li><a data-section-id="cv">cv</a></li>
          <li><a data-section-id="skills">skills</a></li>
          <li><a data-section-id="portfolio">portfolio</a></li>
          <li><a data-section-id="contact">contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      ....
       <section id="skills" data-aos="fade-right">
      <ul>
        <li><i class="fab fa-java"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-js-square"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-node"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-angular"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-html5"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-git"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fab fa-aws"></i></li>
      </ul>
    </section>
```